# Sitecore XM with Redis cache

Tags: session-state, redis

Need to know if Client is having Sitecore XM license. Is redis cache will be allowed to be used with XM license?

Any thoughts will be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Sitecore XM allows you to use Redis as one of the options for a shared session state store:

> ## Supported infrastructure
>
> The Shared Session State Store can be hosted on:
>
> - SQL Server
> - Redis
> - Azure SQL
> - Azure Redis

(from https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/shared-session-state-store.html)

Additional configuration information: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/redis-provider-settings-reference.html